# (index):40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at getanswer ((index):40) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):204)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

Whenever I click the submit button it should validate the answer with the desired value given in the database. How can I solve this error?

The button performs a form submission which contains the table and rows. I have included a piece of code of that.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="getanswer();"> submitanswer </button>

<tr>
  <td>{{Result.id}} ) {{Result.questions}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" id="choice1" name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice1}}">{{Result.choice1}}</td>
</tr>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $(".btn1").show();
    $(".btn1").attr("disabled", true);
  });
});

function getanswer() {
  document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML = "";
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (i = 0; i <= e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i].type == 'radio') {
      if (e[i].checked) {
        document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML += "Q" + e[i].name + "Answer you selected is :" + e[i].value + "<br/>";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is because there's no element with an id of `useranswer` in the DOM, so `document.getElementById("useranswer")` returns undefined. Given the code in the question, that's the only help we can offer.

Comment: it actually returns `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that JavaScript will return `null` for elements that don't exist.

To solve this problem, make sure there is a `#useranswer` element somewhere.

```html
<div id="useranswer"></div>
```